# implementing a centralized content "show-do-not-show" toggle?

Tags: functions, customization

I have many custom templates for different post types, and I am manually inserting a social share bar inside the 'entry-meta' footer in each of those templates. I need a simple centralized way to disable the social share bar without hacking into the plugin.

Basically I have this setup so far:

In **functions.php**:

`update_option( 'show_social_bar', 'true' );`

In my templates I have this check:

```
if( get_option( 'show_social_bar' ) === 'true' ) {
  // show my social share links 
}
```

If I need to turn the bar off, I just set the option to 'false' in **functions.php**. This somehow seems inefficient. Is there a more sensible way?

Comment: Are you looking to do this on a per-post basis?

Comment: @5t3ph: more on a per-template basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad practice to update an option on every page load. You should use a constant instead.

```
define('SHOW_SOCIAL_BAR', true); //functions.php

if(SHOW_SOCIAL_BAR){
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would make it a checkbox on a settings page, that way you're not setting something every load (because MySQL writes are slow) and you have a user-friendly way to make the change.

Comment: Never done it before but would be willing to try. Any nice tutorials come to mind?

Comment: [This one](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-settings-api-part-1-create-a-theme-options-page/) is pretty solid.